# Use drupal_goto with named anchor in url

Tags: url, drupal-7, anchor, goto

i am trying to go to an location choosen by my script.
I'm using `url()` and `drupal_goto()` to archive this, but the fragment-option named at the [url()-documentation-page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) seems not working like i understand it or more likely `drupal_goto()` is changing the link.

The link-string i want should look like:

```
/topsection/section#subsection
```

but instead i'm getting the hash-sign encoded like

```
/topsection/section%23subsection
```

Here is my code:

```
$section = url( '/topsection/' . 'section', array( 'fragment' =>  'subsection', 'alias' => TRUE ) );
drupal_goto( $section );
```

Any help would be nice!
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ha!** just found the solution:

I misunderstood the documentation. 
It is correctly telling that i should use `drupal_goto()` with fragment/anchor passed as option like i would give to `url()`.

This is working:

```
drupal_goto( '/topsection/' . 'section', 
  array( 
    'fragment' => 'subsection',
    'alias' => TRUE ) );
```